# How to compare output of two commands in a batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script to run hotcopy for my Subversion backups. Like this:

```
SET REPOS=D:\Repos
SET BACKUP=C:\Backup

FOR /f %%s IN('DIR /b /a:d %REPOS%') DO (
  svnadmin hotcopy %REPOS%\%%s %BACKUP%\%%s
)
```

I want to add a conditional check so that it only runs hotcopy if a repository has changed. Something like this pseudo-code:

```
if (svnlook youngest repo1 != svnlook youngest backup1) {
  //do hotcopy as above
}
```

How do I implement this in a batch script? I.e. how do I compare the output of two commands in a batch script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested (i have not an environment where to do it) but this is the skeleton

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    set "REPOS=D:\Repos"
    set "BACKUP=C:\Backup"

    for /d %%r in ("%REPOS%") do (

        set "sourceVersion="
        for /f %%a in ('svnlook youngest "%%~fr"') do set "sourceVersion=%%a"

        set "targetVersion="
        for /f %%a in ('svnlook youngest "%BACKUP%\%%~nxr"') do set "targetVersion=%%a"

        if not "!sourceVersion!"=="!targetVersion!" (
            svnadmin hotcopy "%%~fr" "%BACKUP%\%%~nxr"
        )
    )
```